# chance of getting AB before AA

Tags: probability, martingales, stopping-times

> What is the probability of a monkey typing random letts and getting AB before getting AA.

We are learning probability using martingale and stopping time. 
 I tried to define T to be the stopping time of getting AB or AA. I wanted to define a martingale $X_n$ s.t $X_T$ would get AA or AB and cheack what's the chance of it being AB. But I could not think of a r.v $X_n$ that would do it.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Thank you,

Comment: This is very easy. If the monkey types $B$ last, then neither $AB$ nor $AA$ can be formed by the last two letters after the monkey types the next letter. On the other hand, if $A$ appears, then after the next letter either $AB$ or $AA$ will have been typed, either with probability $\frac 12$. An $A$ will have to appear with probability $1$, by the law of large numbers. Conditioned on it appearing, $AB$ and $AA$ may be obtained  as the last two letters with probability $\frac 12$ each. Hence, the answer is $\frac 12$.  Make this rigorous using the appropriate objects.